# how to search for something in a database and display it?

Tags: php

I tried this code for displaying an item name, price and a photo from database for searching an item name in a search bar

```
<?php
  try
    {
       require('connection.php');
       
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM items
        where item.item_name like '".$txt1."%' 
        
        $result2=$db->query($sql2);
         if ($result2->rowCount()!=0) {
            foreach ($result2 as $r2) { ?>
                <a href="images/<?php echo $r2['item_photo'] ?>" class="fh5co-card-item image-popup">
                <figure>
                    <div class="overlay"><i class="ti-plus"></i></div>
                     <img src="images/<?php echo $r2['item_photo']?>" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                </figure>
                <div>
                     <?php echo "<p><span  class='price kk'>" ; ?>
                     <p style="font-family:'georgia';text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:black;"><?php echo ($r2['item_name']); ?></span></p>
                     <h2 style="font-family:'georgia';text-align:center;font-size:18px;color:grey;"><?php echo ("BD ".$r2['item_price']); ?></h2>
                 </div>
           <?php }
          } ?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does this return for you? Please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please take a course in php first. Plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: what is the problem in code man? Share us so that we can provide some help

Comment: Your code appears to be very dangerous, and can be exploited with sql injection

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the sql, There is an extra name after where

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM items
        where item.item_name like '".$txt1."%' ;
```

There should be only item_name not item.item_name. Change this as:

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM items
        where item_name like '".$txt1."%';
```

And your code may be exploited with sql injection. Be carefull for production use this code.